# I've edited a workflow but changes are not reflected when run. 

Tags: workflow

I have very little experience in workflows, so I'm pretty sure I'm making a noob mistake here.

I open up the workflow in sharepoint designer, it loads correctly, no errors.

I then make a change, in this case just a url in an email template. When I click "finish" it displays the "Associating workflow with list".

I then run the workflow, I do this by creating a new item in the list, and the email does go out. But the url field I changed was not updated.

The workflow file seems to be saved, but for some reason the changes are not being carried through, so when I run the workflow, only old version.

What step have I not completed to get the workflow changed?

Comment: What SharePoint version you are working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Error : More than 1 workflow needed to be changed.